# Can't parse ArcGIS Services Directory sitemap with lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, lxml

I'm trying to parse all the urls from an ArcGIS services directory sitemap

for example:

http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/?f=sitemap

[image]

Using:

```
from lxml import etree
from urllib.request import urlopen

xml = urlopen('http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/?f=sitemap')
tree = etree.parse(xml)
```

I can't seem to be able to iterate the element tree, let alone find specific tags, like 'loc'

What am I doing wrong or is unconventional with that xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you account for the default namespace (see https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes). Here's an example.

```py
from lxml import etree
from urllib.request import urlopen

req = urlopen("http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/?f=sitemap")

namespaces = {"sm": "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"}

tree = etree.parse(req)

for loc in tree.xpath("//sm:url/sm:loc", namespaces=namespaces):
    print(loc.text)
```

printed output...

```
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/BuildingFootprints/FeatureServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/BuildingFootprints/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/CompositePointLocator/GeocodeServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/dec_lands/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/dec_trails/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FindN/GPServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/gas_station/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Assembly_Districts/FeatureServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Assembly_Districts/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Civil_Boundaries/FeatureServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Civil_Boundaries/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Congressional_Districts/FeatureServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Congressional_Districts/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Exits/FeatureServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Exits/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Hydrography_HollowFill/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Hydrography/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Mesonet/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Place_Points/FeatureServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Place_Points/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Schools/FeatureServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Schools/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Senate_Districts/FeatureServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Senate_Districts/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Streets/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Tax_Parcel_Centroid_Points/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Tax_Parcels_Public/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Tax_Parcels_State_Owned/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYSLayersMap/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYSTaxAssessmentLookup/GPServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/OVS_Sites/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/SAM_Address_Points_Symbolized/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/SAM_Address_Points/MapServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Locators/NYPlace/GeocodeServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Locators/Street_and_Address_Composite/GeocodeServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Locators/Street_NoNum_and_ZipCode_Composite/GeocodeServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer
http://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/RasterUtilities/GPServer
```